# Will having multiple distros at the same time detoriorate hard disk life?

Tags: partitioning

I have a 5400 rpm hdd with **5 separate partition** each containing a different distro like Ubuntu, Fedora, OpenSUSE, Debian, Manjaro. I find it really hard to settle down with just one distro. Will the hard disk die soon because of having so many partitions?

Thanks in advance guys...

Comment: That is not a genuine question. Perhaps, I have 9 distros currently installed :-)

Comment: I am sure the presence of how many partitions you want (you could also create 100 partitions) does not change anything for the HDD stress. But after some thoughts, I came to the idea, that it _could_ (not sure, just a very vague idea!) make a difference if one partition, which represents a set of physical cylinders more or less, is used extensively while the others are not. That however could be positive because it reduces the ways the actuator has to move. But it increases the access on that specific set of cylinders. No idea, just sharing thoughts...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is Ubuntu destroying my internal HDD?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/586442/is-ubuntu-destroying-my-internal-hdd)

Answer (score 3):

The short answer is **NO**.

Why would you assume such a thing ?

Comment: Some guy told me as such and I wasn't sure, that why I wanted to confirm.