# How do I hibernate with swap file without swapping?

Tags: usb, lubuntu, swap, hibernate

Well, I know that my question title is not clear so I'll explain.
.

Background:
I have a laptop with dead battery. (Won't even charge) It also have dead hard drive. (Thrown away) And have 1000MiB RAM just to let you know for walk through.

So I decided to use a 16GB USB stick with single flash chip to install Lubuntu 15.10. It is working great although the stick is a bit of bottle neck since it only have one chip.

I knew if I made swap partition on it, it would slow down even worse so I decided to not make one.
.

Problem:
I wanted to hibernate my computer but I couldn't without a swap file or swap partition. I can't use stanby 'cause battery is dead. Swap file will try to write quite a bunch of data so it will slow down the computer and kill my USB faster.
.

Question:
How can I make a swap file for hibernate only? I want to hibernate my computer but don't want to it to start using swap for "performance boost."

If there is possible solution, could I get a walk through of it?

Comment: To avoid swapping, you'll need to adjust the swappiness value: http://askubuntu.com/questions/103915/how-do-i-configure-swappiness.

Comment: Please read the entire answer, including the links!  :-)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Hibernate and resume from a swap file](http://askubuntu.com/questions/6769/hibernate-and-resume-from-a-swap-file)

Answer (score 1):

**First of all: a warning** as you're saying:

> the stick is a bit of bottle neck since it only have one chip.

Which makes me suppose you're using an [MLC USB stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-level_cell).  These sticks are slow and prone to errors, so one day *in the near future,* you're going to wake up and find that you've got no system at all and all of your data is lost, as [HDDs die a slow, painful death like cancer, whereas SSDs just suddenly stop working like a heart attack!](https://askubuntu.com/questions/586442/is-ubuntu-destroying-my-internal-hdd/586469#586469)

Therefore:

1. Install your stick for the moment [like here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/600258/can-i-use-a-usb-stick-for-a-normal-install-to-get-platform-adaptability)
2. Buy an [SLC USB stick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-level_cell#Single-level_cell) ASAHP and re-install on that one
3. [Make back-ups of your data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/569679/whats-a-good-back-up-strategy-for-1-desktop-pc) from the SLC stick onto the MLC stick...

#### Data isn't data until it's backed up!

Comment: As you've never accepted an answer on this site before: If this answer helped you, don't forget to click the grey **☑** at the left of this text, which means [Yes, this answer is valid](http://askubuntu.com/help/accepted-answer)!  **;-)**

Comment: USB sticks also tend to randomly corrupt your data quite frequently.  You would not believe how many bug reports get filed from people trying to install Ubuntu using a usb stick and it just corrupted some files they just wrote to it.

Comment: @psusi not randomly: at the end of their life, or with incorrect usage... (people yanking out the USB stick before it had time to wite back changes)  **;-) :P**

Comment: Perhaps they are old, but it is highly unlikely they removed it before the process was done: the startup disk creator is pretty clear when it has finished with the drive.

Answer (score 0):

My computers have lots of RAM, so I never have seen swap space being used to supplement it.
I do use hibernate often so I still define more swap space than I have RAM.
Never noticed this slowing down my computer, but have never tried benchmarking it.
Are you sure using swap space actually slows you down.