# How can I test to see if there something wrong with my SSD?

Tags: ssd, 17.10, performance, disk

So a few weeks ago I update to 17.10 and at pretty much the same time I updated to Android Studio 3, and it was probably a mistake updating both as now I don't know where the problem lies.

Basically it seems like disk IO has gotten really bad. At first I noticed I was swapping so I doubled my ram (32 gigs now) and I'm never swapping anymore. But the machine still pretty much freezes when disk IO happens. By freezes I mean it will get really slow, to the point that I can type and I won't see what I'm typing for a few seconds, often I'll get a long string of one key when that happens.

When I go to commit my code, Android Studio will do an analysis of the code and the UI just freezes while it does that. Takes a few seconds. None of these issues used to happen before updating both things.

Also, when the cloud station backup runs to my NAS, it gets ridiculously slow.

I have a `Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB` SSD.

So what can I run to see what the issue is?

Thanks.

Edit:

Smartctl output:

```
smartctl 6.6 2016-05-31 r4324 [x86_64-linux-4.13.0-16-generic] (local build)
Copyright (C) 2002-16, Bruce Allen, Christian Franke, www.smartmontools.org

=== START OF INFORMATION SECTION ===
Model Family:     Samsung based SSDs
Device Model:     Samsung SSD 850 PRO 512GB
Serial Number:    S250NSAG809789J
LU WWN Device Id: 5 002538 8a0af305f
Firmware Version: EXM02B6Q
User Capacity:    512,110,190,592 bytes [512 GB]
Sector Size:      512 bytes logical/physical
Rotation Rate:    Solid State Device
Device is:        In smartctl database [for details use: -P show]
ATA Version is:   ACS-2, ATA8-ACS T13/1699-D revision 4c
SATA Version is:  SATA 3.1, 6.0 Gb/s (current: 6.0 Gb/s)
Local Time is:    Tue Nov 28 16:22:20 2017 CST
SMART support is: Available - device has SMART capability.
SMART support is: Enabled

=== START OF READ SMART DATA SECTION ===
SMART overall-health self-assessment test result: PASSED

General SMART Values:
Offline data collection status:  (0x00) Offline data collection activity
                    was never started.
                    Auto Offline Data Collection: Disabled.
Self-test execution status:      (   0) The previous self-test routine completed
                    without error or no self-test has ever 
                    been run.
Total time to complete Offline 
data collection:        (    0) seconds.
Offline data collection
capabilities:            (0x53) SMART execute Offline immediate.
                    Auto Offline data collection on/off support.
                    Suspend Offline collection upon new
                    command.
                    No Offline surface scan supported.
                    Self-test supported.
                    No Conveyance Self-test supported.
                    Selective Self-test supported.
SMART capabilities:            (0x0003) Saves SMART data before entering
                    power-saving mode.
                    Supports SMART auto save timer.
Error logging capability:        (0x01) Error logging supported.
                    General Purpose Logging supported.
Short self-test routine 
recommended polling time:    (   2) minutes.
Extended self-test routine
recommended polling time:    ( 272) minutes.
SCT capabilities:          (0x003d) SCT Status supported.
                    SCT Error Recovery Control supported.
                    SCT Feature Control supported.
                    SCT Data Table supported.

SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 1
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  5 Reallocated_Sector_Ct   0x0033   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
  9 Power_On_Hours          0x0032   095   095   000    Old_age   Always       -       23126
 12 Power_Cycle_Count       0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       75
177 Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       117
179 Used_Rsvd_Blk_Cnt_Tot   0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
181 Program_Fail_Cnt_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
182 Erase_Fail_Count_Total  0x0032   100   100   010    Old_age   Always       -       0
183 Runtime_Bad_Block       0x0013   100   100   010    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
187 Uncorrectable_Error_Cnt 0x0032   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
190 Airflow_Temperature_Cel 0x0032   070   057   000    Old_age   Always       -       30
195 ECC_Error_Rate          0x001a   200   200   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
199 CRC_Error_Count         0x003e   100   100   000    Old_age   Always       -       0
235 POR_Recovery_Count      0x0012   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       34
241 Total_LBAs_Written      0x0032   099   099   000    Old_age   Always       -       37060089586

SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
No self-tests have been logged.  [To run self-tests, use: smartctl -t]

SMART Selective self-test log data structure revision number 1
 SPAN  MIN_LBA  MAX_LBA  CURRENT_TEST_STATUS
    1        0        0  Not_testing
    2        0        0  Not_testing
    3        0        0  Not_testing
    4        0        0  Not_testing
    5        0        0  Not_testing
Selective self-test flags (0x0):
  After scanning selected spans, do NOT read-scan remainder of disk.
If Selective self-test is pending on power-up, resume after 0 minute delay.
```

df -i output:

```
Filesystem              Inodes   IUsed    IFree IUse% Mounted on
udev                   4096227     613  4095614    1% /dev
tmpfs                  4111096    1024  4110072    1% /run
/dev/sda1             29908992 4301747 25607245   15% /
tmpfs                  4111096     524  4110572    1% /dev/shm
tmpfs                  4111096       5  4111091    1% /run/lock
tmpfs                  4111096      18  4111078    1% /sys/fs/cgroup
tmpfs                  4111096      17  4111079    1% /run/user/122
tmpfs                  4111096     458  4110638    1% /run/user/1000
/home/mydir/.Private 29908992 4301747 25607245   15% /home/mydir
```

Comment: Run `smartctl` command, post the output. It might reveal something about your SSD health. Also check inode count with `df -i`. Swap and RAM usage might be worth checking too for io stufd

Comment: Added the output. Thanks. According to top and the gui monitor app I have zero swap usage since adding more ram.

Comment: I thought `pre-fail` was just the type of statistic, not the status?

Comment: Yes, `TYPE` column only indicates the type of statistic. `VALUE` column is supposed to be compared with `THRESH` column, and it's bad only when `VALUE` gets low enough that it approaches `THRESH`. In your case it's alright. I looked only briefly through it last time on phone, so my previous comment was wrong.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "Also, when the cloud station backup runs to my NAS, it gets ridiculously slow." Why did you do `df -i`, inodes is not really useful in this case, please provide `df -h` or `df`, it might be that you are running out of space (less than say 15% available) on the drive, which causes slowdowns....

Comment: Cloud station backup is a backup utility from the company that makes my NAS.

Comment: Sorry hit enter before finishing the reply. I think I am down to 20% or so, I'll have to check tonight when I'm near the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Install **Gnome Disk Utility** and check tests for wear-leveling-count and SMART Data or any similar.

The higher the reported percentage, the more worn your SSD is, which means you are more likely to encounter problems.

Install using:

`apt-get install gnome-disk-utility`

Launch via command line

`sudo palimpsest`

or via the application menu under the name **Disk Utility**.

Comment: Wear leveling count is 118.  How do I convert that to a percentage?

Comment: @casoloroz 118 is the raw data value (typically in hexadecimal). You don't convert it to a percentage.

Answer (score 1):

SMART normalized data counts down, ***not*** up!

The specific command you're likely looking for is:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda | grep Media_Wearout_Indicator
```

The higher this is, the more *likely* you are to run into issues. As an aside, I would recommend considering replacing your drive after this hits:

- 50% - Mission Critical Drives (things that, for reasons beyond the scope here are **NEEDED** to be accessible ***no matter what***.)
- 30% - your /home drive (your movies/music/personal files, things you care about having at hand)
- 20% everything else (drives only brought online for backups before being committed to cold-storage, drives that hold OSes you only use occasionally, etc.)

Comment: Are you talking about this one: `Wear_Leveling_Count     0x0013   098   098   000    Pre-fail  Always       -       118` ? I don't know what 118 means, that can't possibly be the percentage, can it? it can't go above 100, right?

Comment: @casolorz the above is the correct command and 118 is not the % but 98 is and you're in "pre-fail" status: **Back-up right now**.  I mean like: STOP USING THE DISK and do a `ddrescue` right now onto a bigger disk because [SSDs die suddenly without warning](https://askubuntu.com/a/586469/344926)

Comment: `Pre-Fail` is the type, not the status. So 98 sounds really bad but on another post I read it sounded like the number goes backwards. You can see my smart output on my post.

Comment: ok, after my brain derped earlier I found it prudend to update my answer and leave information gleaned from http://www.z-a-recovery.com/manual/smart.aspx there

Comment: @casolorz your normalized count is 98% meaning that your drive is near perfect condition! YAY!

Comment: Anymore ideas? I guess maybe I just need to clear some space on the drive.

Comment: @casolorz do yourself a favor and check iotop or nmon (I prefer the latter) this will let you identify exactly what processes are eating your disk io and causing the thrashing

Answer (score 0):

According to your log output, you've never run a smart test on the drive. There are a couple ways you can do this. One way is via the GUI as described in my answer [here.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/528072/how-can-i-check-the-smart-status-of-a-ssd-or-hdd-on-current-versions-of-ubuntu-1/528077#528077)

Another way is to issue the command via the command line as described by the answer [here](https://askubuntu.com/a/528076/225694)

Results of any tests are added to the log as shown in the snippet of output from the command `sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda` below from my TOSHIBA THNSNH128GBST SSD:

```
SMART Error Log Version: 1
No Errors Logged

SMART Self-test log structure revision number 1
Num  Test_Description    Status                  Remaining  LifeTime(hours)  LBA_of_first_error
# 1  Short offline       Completed without error       00%     14965         -
# 2  Short offline       Completed without error       00%      1955         -
# 3  Short offline       Completed without error       00%       701         -
```